# Combine similar siblings in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a list of objects, and I need to merge siblings that are similar according to a given criteria. The point is to limit the number of similar rows displayed in a table.

Take for example this scenario:

```
const items = [
  { from: 0,  to: 2,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 2,  to: 4,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 4,  to: 7,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 7,  to: 8,  percent: 50 },
  { from: 8,  to: 9,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 9,  to: 10, percent: 70 },
  { from: 10, to: 13, percent: 30 },
];
```

Here, similar rows that should be merged are the ones with the same percentage:

```
const similar = (a, b) => a.percent == b.percent;
```

And they can be merged by adjusting the `from` and `to` fields:

```
const combine = (...items) => ({
    from: items[0].from,
    to: items[items.length - 1].to,
    percent: items[0].percent,
})
```

The result should be:

```
const combined = combineSimilar(items, combine, similar);
```

```
[
  { from: 0,  to: 7,  percent: 70 }, // 0, 1, 2 merged
  { from: 7,  to: 8,  percent: 50 }, // 3 as is
  { from: 8,  to: 10, percent: 70 }, // 4, 5 merged
  { from: 10, to: 13, percent: 30 }, // 6 as is
];
```

I "see" what needs to be done, but are having problems boiling it down to an actual algorithm. Tried googling, but all I can find are algorithms for duplicates in full lists, not just within siblings, and removing the duplicates rather than combining them.

Maybe this kind of algorithm is just called something else than what I'm searching for?

Anyone able to help me implement this? I.e. how to finish the following function?

```
function combineSimilar<T>(
  subject: T[],
  combineFn: (...items: T[]) => T,
  similarFn: (a: T, b: T) => boolean
) {
  if(subject.length < 2) return [...subject];

  // ??
}
```

---

**Some clarifications:**

- Relying on `combineFn` and `similarFn` is central because the criteria for which rows are considered similar, and how to merge similar rows, will vary from dataset to dataset.
- The `subject` is shared and might be used/displayed in other places as well, so the original array and objects should not be "messed with". The objects from `items` could be passed through, but must not have any values changed, and the `items` array should remain unchanged (same number of items, same order).

Sorry I didn't mention these points properly/at all before, as they do change the problem quite a bit...

Comment: is the array sorted?

Comment: Are the from-to always continuous? E.g. You have 0-2,2-4,4-7. Would 0-2,3-4,4-7 be a valid input?

Comment: @NinaScholz The array is _ordered_, i.e. it should keep its existing order, and similar items should be replaced with a single new merged item in their place. If that makes sense 

Comment: @DBS Theoretically, 0-2,3-4,4-7 could be a valid input yes, but in that case one should just need to expand `similar` to be e.g. `(a, b) => a.to === b.from && a.percent == b.percent` (if I got that right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a combination of ideas from other answers here (thanks!) and some more hours of twisting my brain, I've finally found an algorithm that seem to work. And, more importantly, one that works with the `similarFn` and `combineFn` callback functions.

If anyone have suggestions for improvements or alternatives though, that would be much welcome.

```js
function combineSimilar(
    subject,
    similarFn,
    combineFn = (...similar) => similar[0]
) {
    if (subject.length < 2) return [...subject];

    const result = [];

    let similar = [subject[0]];

    for (const item of subject.slice(1))
      if (similarFn(similar[similar.length - 1], item)) {
          similar.push(item);
      } else {
          result.push(combineFn(...similar));
          similar = [item];
      }

    result.push(combineFn(...similar));

    return result;
}

const items = [
  { from: 0,  to: 2,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 2,  to: 4,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 4,  to: 7,  percent: 70 },

  { from: 7,  to: 8,  percent: 50 },

  { from: 8,  to: 9,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 9,  to: 10, percent: 70 },

  { from: 10, to: 13, percent: 30 },
  { from: 13, to: 14, percent: 30 },

  { from: 15, to: 16, percent: 30 }, // NOTE: `from` != `previous.to`
  { from: 16, to: 20, percent: 30 },
];

const similar = (a, b) => a.to === b.from && a.percent === b.percent;

const combine = (...items) => ({
  ...items[0],
  to: items[items.length-1].to
});

const result = combineSimilar(items, similar, combine);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the data, and keep track of the "current" percent value. If different, create a new object (copy of item), and push it in the result array. When the same, just update the `to` field in the last created object.

It is not clear from your question, but maybe you also want to start with a new object, if the `from` value is not the same as the previous `to` value (representing a gap). I have also implemented that:

```js
function combineSimilar(items) {
    // Optionally sort by `from` if not already done
    items.sort((a,b) => a.from - b.from);
    let result = [], curr = {};
    for (let item of items) {
        if (item.percent != curr.percent || item.from > curr.to) {
            result.push(curr = {...item});
        }
        curr.to = item.to;
    }
    return result;
}

const items = [
  { from: 0,  to: 2,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 2,  to: 4,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 4,  to: 7,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 7,  to: 8,  percent: 50 },
  { from: 8,  to: 9,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 9,  to: 10, percent: 70 },
  { from: 10, to: 13, percent: 30 },
];
let result = combineSimilar(items);
console.log(result);
```

#### Using the `similar` and `combine` functions

```js
const similar = (a, b) => a.percent == b.percent;

const combine = (...items) => ({
    ...items[0],
    to: items[items.length - 1].to
});

function combineSimilar(items, similar, combine) {
    // Optionally sort by `from` if not already done
    items.sort((a,b) => a.from - b.from);
    let result = [], curr = {};
    for (let item of items) {
        if (!similar(item, curr)) result.push(curr = {...item});
        Object.assign(curr, combine(curr, item));
    }
    return result;
}

const items = [
  { from: 0,  to: 2,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 2,  to: 4,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 4,  to: 7,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 7,  to: 8,  percent: 50 },
  { from: 8,  to: 9,  percent: 70 },
  { from: 9,  to: 10, percent: 70 },
  { from: 10, to: 13, percent: 30 },
];
let result = combineSimilar(items, similar, combine);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Would this approach work generically, using the `similar` and `combine` callback functions from my question?

Comment: Sure, but I see you already got it to work like that? I didn't think that was the core of your question, but I can update if you wish.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should've been clearer on that point. I'm after the generic algorithm, since this will likely be used in more places, and the both criteria and how to merge the similar objects will vary. For example in my current actual case, there is just a single date and two decimal numbers. The criteria are both numbers being equal within a certain tolerance, and "merging" is simply to pick the item with the oldest date (i.e. the last similar item).

Comment: OK, I added a snippet to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce and check the last item.

```js
const
    items = [{ from: 0,  to: 2,  percent: 70 }, { from: 2,  to: 4,  percent: 70 }, { from: 4,  to: 7,  percent: 70 }, { from: 7,  to: 8,  percent: 50 }, { from: 8,  to: 9,  percent: 70 }, { from: 9,  to: 10, percent: 70 }, { from: 10, to: 13, percent: 30 }],
    result = items.reduce((r, o) => {
        const last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (last && last.percent === o.percent && last.to === o.from) last.to = o.to;
        else r.push({ ...o });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach for unsorted data:

```js
const
    items = [{ from: 7,  to: 8,  percent: 50 }, { from: 8,  to: 9,  percent: 70 }, { from: 9,  to: 10, percent: 70 }, { from: 4,  to: 7,  percent: 70 }, { from: 0,  to: 2,  percent: 70 }, { from: 10, to: 13, percent: 30 }, { from: 2,  to: 4,  percent: 70 }],
    result = items.reduce((r, o) => {
        const 
            previous = r.findIndex(q => q.to === o.from && q.percent === o.percent),
            next = r.findIndex(q => q.from === o.to && q.percent === o.percent);

        if (previous !== -1 && next !== -1) {
            r[previous].to = r.splice(next, 1)[0].to;
        } else if (previous !== -1) {
            r[previous].to = o.to;
        } else if (next !== -1) {
            r[next].from = o.from;
        } else r.push({ ...o });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: does this approach work also for data that is not as structured/sorted as provided with the OP's  scenario? Or asking it in another way, is the additional sorting as shown in *trincot*'s approach obsolet within your solution?

Comment: @PeterSeliger, no, it works oly for sorted data, as op confirmed. for unsorted data, the task is more difficult because of the part who may be joined at the end.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Not sure what your case is, but does the concept of _siblings_ even make sense in an unordered list? 

Comment: @Svish ... I was not doubting the concept of siblings. What I saw was an array of similar objects. From my experience, if one is not in control of the creation of such data, but one's consuming algorithm depends on a specific order, one needs to write this process fail save, thus sanitizing/assuring the correct sorting order oneself.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Ah, right, I see what you mean now. In this case the order of the list is so linked to the whole point of the algorithm though, so I wouldn't add any fail-safe/sanitizing into this function. I would if it would cause the algorithm to _crash_, but in my solution at least, it would just cause the end result to be different from what one wanted.

Comment: @NinaScholz Would this approach work generically, using the `similar` and `combine` callback functions from my question?

Comment: @Svish, no, you need to get the previous item and/or the next item/indices and take one of the four actions, depending on the result.